# Load custom qsqlite instead of Qt's qsqlite plugin

Tags: qt, sqlite

I have created my own qsqlite.dll and I want to use it instead of Qt's qsqlite plugin only in one Qt project. I don't want replace Qt's qsqlite.dll. How to do this? What should I change in  pro file to use my own qsqlite.dll and don't load Qt's qsqlite.dll?

Comment: Hi, you just have to re compile the Qt Sqlite plugin using sources available here: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: I already recompiled sqlite plugin and I already have qsqlite.dll. But I can't load it from my custom place (for example from d:\QTDev\3rdparty\bin\). If I replaced Qt's qsqlite.dll with my qsqlite.dll it is working good. But I don't want replace Qt's standard plugin. I want to use it only in one project.

Comment: If you use sql, you put something like `QT += sql`. This keyword is just a shortcut to define every paths you need with sql so probably standart Qt sqlite's plugin. So remove this and add your own lib with `-L/*My_lib_path*/ -lqsqlite`

Comment: Hi Martinad, I tried your solution. But its not working. To many "undefined reference"s to db functions

Comment: Well, I really can't help you about undefined references without seeing your code :x If your own qsqlite.dll has no dependencies (except standard libs) and if you only use symbols defined in your dll, it should work.

Comment: What compiler? Cl or g++?